# Can adverbs modify implied words in this case?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

> I watched soccer with my hands warmly in the pockets.

This is what I made.

Actually, "warmly" is meant to modify omitted "being". (I watched soccer with my hands being warmly in the pockets).

Is it possible?

Comment: It's no different to *He shut the door, with his family safely inside.* Personally, I have no particular preference between that adverbial form and the explicitly adjectival form *...with his family **safe** inside,* and I don't think that stylistic choice has any effect on the meaning. But adverbial ***warmly*** in the cited example sounds at least *slightly* awkward to me, even though it's obviously syntactically fine. Since the "flat adjective" seems to work in all contexts, I suggest you use that format always.

Comment: *...with my hands **being warmly** in my pockets* sounds [*really* weird](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being+warmly+in%2Cbeing+warm+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) to me compared to *...with my hands **being warm** in my pockets*  (which itself is slightly less weird without ***being***).

Comment: In general, you would use an **adjective**, *not an adverb*, with forms of the verb "to be." *Correct:* "The cat is fluffy." *Wrong:* "The cat is fluffily."

Answer (score 1):

> *I watched soccer with* [*my hands warmly in my pockets*].

The bracketed element is a verbless clause. The whole "with" PP functions as an adjunct to the clause "I watched soccer".

It has a subject+predicate structure, but with no verb in the predicate.

"With" is semantically similar to "have", cf. "I had my hands warmly in my pockets".

Comment: "Warmly in my pockets" is a preposition phrase in which the adverb "warmly" modifies the PP "in my pockets".